# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' not working well

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, cors

I'm trying to load custom fonts across domains. but they can't be loaded due to error in browser

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource

Even when I added the needed headers to the response.. the problem persists (Also I read many similar questions on StackOverflow but nothing worked)

[This is an example](http://jmu.edu.iq/font/) of the page which show the problem

[image]

---

In the folder which contains font files .. I added `.htaccess` the following

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Timing-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

and when testing the headers [here](http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php) .. they look to be working fine

[image]

---

but the fonts still can't be loaded :(

So is there any way to make 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' work properly ??

Comment: those look like they are on the same origin.

Comment: no they aren't @DanielA.White .. example is on jmu.edu.iq while font files on swiftdeer.com

Answer (score 0):

Your regex expression is not property configurated, because you are starting with "\.()" you are not allowing content at the beginin of the name, you are only allowing names like .ttf, so no one file will match.

A correct expression could be "((^$)|(^.+\.(ttf|ttx)$))", as is shown in this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/648262/filesmatch-configuration-to-restrict-file-extensions-served)